# Need sample VB.NET Object to JSON

Tags: .net, sql, json

Trying to get pure JSON from .asmx page with SQL calls. Can't seem to get it. Every post I find is either in c# or not what I'm after. Serialization causes a 1 dimensional array issue. I need to get data from MS access database on my web server for small java app.

```
<%@ WebService class="GetDBStudent" %>

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Data
imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

'<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="com.mcfrsit.GetDBStudent")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
Public Class GetDBStudent
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
Public Class Students
    Public StudentID As String
    Public LastName As String
    Public FirstName As String
    Public Affiliation As String
    Public ClassName As String
    Public DateCompleted As DateTime
End Class

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetArray() As Students()

    ' Create a connection string
    Dim DBConnection As String =        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("OdbcServices").ToString
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM ClassRecordsEnrollmentsQry WHERE [Affiliation] = 'DFRS'"
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()

    Dim daTitles As New Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()

    Dim dsTitles As New DataSet("CrossTab")
    Conn.Open(DBConnection, "", "", -1)

    Try
        rs.Open(sql, DBConnection, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic, 1)

        daTitles.Fill(dsTitles, rs, "Students")
        'create object array, using row count as upper dim
        Dim objStudents As Students() = New Students(dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1) {}

        'loop through dataset to add data to object array
        Dim intRsCount As Int16
        For intRsCount = 0 To dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim intCsCount As Int16
            For intCsCount = 0 To dsTitles.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                'Dim strColName As String = dsTitles.Tables(0).Columns(intCsCount)
            Next
            objStudents(intRsCount) = New Students
            objStudents(intRsCount).StudentID = dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows(intRsCount)(0)
            objStudents(intRsCount).LastName = dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows(intRsCount)(1)
            objStudents(intRsCount).FirstName = dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows(intRsCount)(2)
            objStudents(intRsCount).Affiliation = dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows(intRsCount)(3)
            objStudents(intRsCount).ClassName = dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows(intRsCount)(4)
            objStudents(intRsCount).DateCompleted = dsTitles.Tables(0).Rows(intRsCount)(5)
        Next

        'Return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objStudents)
        Return objStudents

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Response.Write("Sorting is not supported in the view")
    Finally
        Conn.Close()
    End Try
End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Returned Function as Object and worked fine...

However the JSON string returned looks like:

```
[{"text":"text2"}]
```

Why the extra "[" and "]" at the start and end?